# How to retrieve MongoBinData to a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, mongodb, bin

I have successfully stored an image into a MongoDB database, since it is stored as a Base64 type information; I want to retrieve that BinData to a string. How do I do that? Here I am finding my document using input 'Email'.

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->mydb2->mycol2;

$result = $db->find(array('Email'=>$em));

foreach( $result as $key){
        $susername = $key['Email'];
        $imagebody = $key['pic'];   
    }
echo $imagebody;
```

?>

**EDIT**:

As Haresh has said

```
$imagebody = $key['pic']->bin
```

works perfectly. But it returns me something like Raw data but if I write this

```
$imagebody = base64_encode($key['pic']->bin);
```

then it returns me exact Base64 format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongobindata.tostring.php)**

> To access the contents of a MongoBinData, use the bin field which return the string **Mongo Binary Data**

So Try this:

```
$imagebody = $key['pic']->bin
```

Hope this works for you.